# SSH connection is broken down when wireguard is connected

Tags: networking, wireguard

I am going to connect to the vps by ssh and connect to the wireguard vpn service on it.

But as soon as I execute the wireguard client, ssh connection is broken down.

Of course I know this is because routing rules are changed, and fixed those issues in case of OpenVPN, but it doesn't work at the moment.

What is different in wireguard?

This is the client config file.

```
# TorGuard WireGuard Config
[Interface]
PrivateKey = uEHhYaGQy9eV5NP++IDlf/ffWrF8siKE0q79PYXHfWY=
ListenPort = 51820
DNS = 1.1.1.1
Address = 10.10.7.15/24

[Peer]
PublicKey = dHeUCCVg8iBJWTOGOY3KpqlSQhvK6+rug9p44hHUbS0=
AllowedIPs = 0.0.0.0/0
Endpoint = 46.107.90.26:1443
PersistentKeepalive = 25
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: if you use `AllowedIPS = 0.0.0.0/1, 128.0.0.0/1` does that fix your issue?

Comment: They are essentially the same, aren't they?

Comment: yeah, that would be good solution also, but is there any other one without modifing conf?

Comment: Probably add a routing exception for the IP addresses (source and/or dest) used by ssh. As details are not provided in the question, can't guess more. You could provide  the results of `ip -br link; ip -br address; ip route; ip rule` and any additional table if any to get an idea. Once before and once after having WireGuard up (eg: through an `at` command).

Comment: Use a different device, which is not using wireguard, to ssh in and make changes.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can do this

```
route add -host <Your-Public-IP> gw <SSH-Server-Gateway-IP>
```

This way at least, your PC can stay connected

Answer (score 0):

Just add a PostUp/Down step to always route traffic to your IP through the main interface and not though the wireguard's interface.

```
PostUp   = ip route add <your public ip>/32 dev eth0
PostDown = ip route del <your public ip>/32 dev eth0
```